# RS-485 Checksum Reverse Engineering (Watlow EZ-Zone PM)

Tags: hardware, serial-communication

I am trying to reverse engineer a two wire RS-485 standard serial bus interface to talk to a [Watlow EZ-Zone PM](https://www.watlow.com/products/controllers/ez-zone-pm-controller.cfm?famid=19) of which I have not been able to find any documentation of the protocol. I have managed to figure out most of the hex commands except for the "check bytes" by sniffing the serial communications from the [Labview driver](http://sine.ni.com/apps/utf8/niid_web_display.model_page?p_model_id=16725) (which doesn't work for my particular application).

**I am having trouble figuring out the 3 check bytes. Any help is appreciated.**

Example hex command:

```
                                       Instance
        Zone                 Parameter  |
         ||                      |---| ||
55 FF 05 10 00 00 06 E8 01 03 01 04 01 01 E3 99
                     ^^                   ^^ ^^
                  check byte           check bytes
```

The first check byte only changes with the bytes before it:

```
55 FF 05 10 00 00 06 E8 01 03 01 04 01 01 E3 99
55 FF 05 11 00 00 06 61 01 03 01 04 01 01 E3 99
55 FF 05 12 00 00 06 F9 01 03 01 04 01 01 E3 99
55 FF 05 13 00 00 06 70 01 03 01 04 01 01 E3 99
55 FF 05 14 00 00 06 CA 01 03 01 04 01 01 E3 99
```

The second two bytes only change with the bytes after the first check byte:

```
55 FF 05 10 00 00 06 E8 01 03 01 04 01 01 E3 99
55 FF 05 10 00 00 06 E8 01 03 01 04 02 01 8B B3
55 FF 05 10 00 00 06 E8 01 03 01 04 03 01 53 AA
55 FF 05 10 00 00 06 E8 01 03 01 04 04 01 5B E7
55 FF 05 10 00 00 06 E8 01 03 01 04 05 01 83 FE
55 FF 05 10 00 00 06 E8 01 03 01 05 05 01 5F A4
55 FF 05 10 00 00 06 E8 01 03 01 06 05 01 3B 4B
55 FF 05 10 00 00 06 E8 01 03 01 07 05 01 E7 11
55 FF 05 10 00 00 06 E8 01 03 01 08 05 01 20 5B
55 FF 05 10 00 00 06 E8 01 03 01 09 05 01 FC 01
55 FF 05 10 00 00 06 E8 01 03 01 0A 05 01 98 EE
```

I did find reference to a CRC checksum in the Watlow Modbus documentation. However I have no idea what the polynomial is. Any ideas?

Comment: What would be the command to send the SETPOINT and read the PV?

Comment: @JorgeCapura I actually programmed this in Labview, discussion and VIs posted over on the Labview Forum: http://forums.ni.com/t5/Instrument-Control-GPIB-Serial/Watlow-EZ-Zone-PM-ENET-RS-485/td-p/3079711

Comment: Is there any source code that I can download? I am trying to ralk to it using Linux. To bad they don’t make a Linux interface for it. Thanks Monito

Comment: I only programmed it in labview. Watlows dll is windows only. You could probably use python and pyserial.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I downloaded the [EZ-ZONE Configurator](http://www.watlow.com/downloads/en/software/ezzone.cfm) and reverse engineered it to see how it works.

The serial data you're seeing is actually the [BACnet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BACnet) MS/TP (master-slave/token-passing) protocol. You can find the [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) protocl decoder for it [here](http://anonsvn.wireshark.org/wireshark/trunk/epan/dissectors/packet-mstp.c). However, to save you the time, I'll help you get to the meat of calculating those check bytes.

In BACnet parlance, `55 FF` is called the "preamble", the first check byte is called the "Header CRC", the last two check bytes are called the "Data CRC", etc. For simplification though, let's call `b[]` your byte array: `b[0]` = `55`, `b[1]` = `FF`, etc.

The first check byte (a.k.a. "Header CRC") (`b[7]`) is calculated using the BACnet 8-bit CRC as follows.

We first define our CRC table:

```
BYTE crc[256] =
{
    0x00, 0xfe, 0xff, 0x01, 0xfd, 0x03, 0x02, 0xfc,
    0xf9, 0x07, 0x06, 0xf8, 0x04, 0xfa, 0xfb, 0x05,
    0xf1, 0x0f, 0x0e, 0xf0, 0x0c, 0xf2, 0xf3, 0x0d,
    0x08, 0xf6, 0xf7, 0x09, 0xf5, 0x0b, 0x0a, 0xf4,
    0xe1, 0x1f, 0x1e, 0xe0, 0x1c, 0xe2, 0xe3, 0x1d,
    0x18, 0xe6, 0xe7, 0x19, 0xe5, 0x1b, 0x1a, 0xe4,
    0x10, 0xee, 0xef, 0x11, 0xed, 0x13, 0x12, 0xec,
    0xe9, 0x17, 0x16, 0xe8, 0x14, 0xea, 0xeb, 0x15,
    0xc1, 0x3f, 0x3e, 0xc0, 0x3c, 0xc2, 0xc3, 0x3d,
    0x38, 0xc6, 0xc7, 0x39, 0xc5, 0x3b, 0x3a, 0xc4,
    0x30, 0xce, 0xcf, 0x31, 0xcd, 0x33, 0x32, 0xcc,
    0xc9, 0x37, 0x36, 0xc8, 0x34, 0xca, 0xcb, 0x35,
    0x20, 0xde, 0xdf, 0x21, 0xdd, 0x23, 0x22, 0xdc,
    0xd9, 0x27, 0x26, 0xd8, 0x24, 0xda, 0xdb, 0x25,
    0xd1, 0x2f, 0x2e, 0xd0, 0x2c, 0xd2, 0xd3, 0x2d,
    0x28, 0xd6, 0xd7, 0x29, 0xd5, 0x2b, 0x2a, 0xd4,
    0x81, 0x7f, 0x7e, 0x80, 0x7c, 0x82, 0x83, 0x7d,
    0x78, 0x86, 0x87, 0x79, 0x85, 0x7b, 0x7a, 0x84,
    0x70, 0x8e, 0x8f, 0x71, 0x8d, 0x73, 0x72, 0x8c,
    0x89, 0x77, 0x76, 0x88, 0x74, 0x8a, 0x8b, 0x75,
    0x60, 0x9e, 0x9f, 0x61, 0x9d, 0x63, 0x62, 0x9c,
    0x99, 0x67, 0x66, 0x98, 0x64, 0x9a, 0x9b, 0x65,
    0x91, 0x6f, 0x6e, 0x90, 0x6c, 0x92, 0x93, 0x6d,
    0x68, 0x96, 0x97, 0x69, 0x95, 0x6b, 0x6a, 0x94,
    0x40, 0xbe, 0xbf, 0x41, 0xbd, 0x43, 0x42, 0xbc,
    0xb9, 0x47, 0x46, 0xb8, 0x44, 0xba, 0xbb, 0x45,
    0xb1, 0x4f, 0x4e, 0xb0, 0x4c, 0xb2, 0xb3, 0x4d,
    0x48, 0xb6, 0xb7, 0x49, 0xb5, 0x4b, 0x4a, 0xb4,
    0xa1, 0x5f, 0x5e, 0xa0, 0x5c, 0xa2, 0xa3, 0x5d,
    0x58, 0xa6, 0xa7, 0x59, 0xa5, 0x5b, 0x5a, 0xa4,
    0x50, 0xae, 0xaf, 0x51, 0xad, 0x53, 0x52, 0xac,
    0xa9, 0x57, 0x56, 0xa8, 0x54, 0xaa, 0xab, 0x55
};
```

And next we can calculate `b[7]`:

```
b[7] = ~crc[b[6] ^ crc[b[5] ^ crc[b[4] ^ crc[b[3] ^ crc[~b[2]]]]]]
```

To calculate the value of the last two check bytes ("Data CRC"):

Perform a CRC-16 of the 6 bytes between the first check byte and the last two check bytes (in your first example, this would be the bytes `01 03 01 04 01 01`), with `0xFFFF` (`-1`) as the initial value for the CRC-16, and `0x8408` as the polynomial. Then bit-flip (a.k.a. "not", a.k.a. "invert") the result and read it in little-endian.

Comment: For anyone curious as to how I determined that this was BACnet MS/TP, I found the non-standard 8-bit CRC table in the data-link driver and Googled for its data. In hindsight, just [Googling for the sample data in the question](https://www.google.com/search?q=55+FF+protocol) would have been much faster :)

Comment: Thanks so much! I spent 2 weeks on and off trying to figure this out and u did it in an hour. lol. Just have to search for the right thing...

Comment: "Just have to search for the right thing..." -- Nope, it's more about reverse engineering the code. The Google search only came up because I wondered if this was a standard protocol. But I never could have extracted the checksum algorithms without reverse engineering the code.

Comment: The header check byte should be this: `b[7] = 256+~crc[b[6] ^ crc[b[5] ^ crc[b[4] ^ crc[b[3] ^ crc[~b[2]]]]]]` right? missing the `256+`? Thanks again!

Comment: The header check byte is a single 8-bit byte, so `256 == 0`. No need to add it to the formula.

Comment: I couldn't get 0x8408 to work. I was successful using the reflection of your polynomial: 0x1021 with a reversed algorithm. For the python crcmod, this corresponds to `crcmod.mkCrcFun(0x11021, 0, True, 0xFFFF)` not sure why I had to mirror it.